# Erro ao tentar mudar o Locale configurado utilizando uma biblioteca em dart

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou tentando fazer a configuração de um novo `locale` em outra tela do aplicativo, mas ele fala que o objeto que tento acessar está nulo, mas fiz exatamente como o exemplo, não estou achando o erro.

```
data.changeLocale(newLocale);
```

Ele dá o seguinte Erro:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'changeLocale' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: changeLocale(Instance of 'Locale')
```

Eu não consigo achar o erro, fiz parecido com o exemplo oficial da biblioteca que estou utilizando a EasyLocation v 1.3.0
Link do exemplo :[Link para exemplo do github](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)
O flutter doctor não detecta nenhuma issue, está tudo correto com o ambiente.
Qualquer informação a mais que for necessária estarei de prontidão.

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recase/recase.dart';
List languages =[];

Map<String,dynamic> locales = new Map();


Locale makeLocale(String localeString){

   if(localeString!= null) {
     Locale locale;
     String language = localeString;
     String languageCode;
     String countryCode;

     int firstLetterLangIndex = 0;
     int secondLetterLangIndex = 2;
     int firstLetterCountryIndex = 3;
     int secondLetterCountryIndex = 5;

     languageCode =
         language.substring(firstLetterLangIndex, secondLetterLangIndex);
     countryCode =
         language.substring(firstLetterCountryIndex, secondLetterCountryIndex);

     locale = Locale(languageCode, countryCode);
     return locale;
   }
   else{
     print("teste"+localeString);
     return null;
   }
}


void buildListLanguages(BuildContext context){
  languages =[];
  String configDataString = AppLocalizations.of(context).tr("config.otherLangs");
  List configStringList= configDataString.split(",");
  print(configStringList);

  int configStringIndex =0;
  do{
   if(configStringIndex % 2 ==0)
     languages.add(configStringList[configStringIndex]);
   else
     locales.addAll({configStringList[configStringIndex-1]:configStringList[configStringIndex]});
   configStringIndex++;

  }while(configStringIndex < configStringList.length);
}
class selecPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _selecPageState createState() => _selecPageState(
  ); }

class _selecPageState extends State<selecPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    buildListLanguages(context);
    TextStyle itemStyle =TextStyle(fontSize: 40,
    );
    ReCase rcTitle = new ReCase(AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('selectPage.desc'));
    var data = EasyLocalizationProvider.of(context).data;
    return EasyLocalizationProvider(
      data:data,
     child: CupertinoPageScaffold(
       navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
         middle: Text(rcTitle.sentenceCase),
       ),
       child:ListView.builder(
         itemCount: languages.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return GestureDetector(
             child:Card(child: Text(languages[index],textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: itemStyle,)),
             onTap: (){
               this.setState(() {
                 String tempLocaleString = locales[languages[index]];
                 tempLocaleString = tempLocaleString.replaceAll(" ","");
                 Locale newLocale = makeLocale(tempLocaleString);
                 data.changeLocale(newLocale);
                 data.saveLocale();
                 Navigator.pop(context);
               });

             },

           );
         },
       ) ,
     ),

    );



       ;
  }
}

/// fazer o recase de cada linguagem
/// construinfdo a lista de linguagens
/// e então usar a seleção para alterar  idioma
/// mandar mensagem toast para reiniciar se for necessário
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você provavelmente não está instanciando o `EasyLocation`.

Na documentação do GitHub que você nos mostrou é dito para instanciar o controlador na `main` do teu projeto, dessa forma:

```
void main() => runApp(EasyLocalization(child: MyApp()));
```

O `EasyLocationProvider` vai buscar na herança da árvore do teu Widget pela instancia criada na inicialização do app.

Caso você tenha já instanciado, então acredito que esse ponto onde você está tentando chamar o provider está fora do contexto principal, o ponto que digo é a tela `_selecPageState`.